# Emotion classifier: overfitting the training dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, overfitting

I'm working on a binary classification model over the RAVDESS dataset with a CNN model.

These are the performances on the train and validation set

[image]

and these are the performance on the test set

[image]

for the unbalanced class distribution, the metrics that I need to check are recall, fscore, and precision. This is the class distribution

[image]

but I'm trying so many different setups of the same CNN, and this is something like the best result. I still decreased the size of the CNN and used augmentation tecniques.

**Question:** What can I do to decrease the overfitting on training data and get the validation error closer to the training error?

My training dataset shape is `(8144, 323, 1)`
and this is the model

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256, 8, padding='same', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256, 8, padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(8)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 8, padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 8, padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 8, padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 8, padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(8)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 8, padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 8, padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0001, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)
loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
model.summary()
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy', fscore, precision, recall])
```

while I'm using some TensorFlow callback such as EarlyStopping and ReduceLROnPlateau

Comment: I don't se overfitting, the validation error is still going down

Comment: That's true, but I can't reach to decrease the validation error, while the epochs are increasing, both errors decrease, but the validation error is slower than the training error.
I have no idea how to solve this problem, I just thought that it was an overfitting problem. I just want try to get validation error closer to the training one.

Comment: I think you should edit your Q so it is only about overfiting and ask another Q about augmentation techniques for audio data. You might also look here for an answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overfitting

Comment: I'll do, thanks